# Multiple input how to keep old values when reselecting files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have simple multiple selection input

`<input multiple="true" type="file" name="image_name[]" />`

Now i would like to keep selecting files with this one input and then submit my form
what i mean after selecting some files if i try to do it once more my old selection is removed, is there some kind of way to keep adding selections to that input?

If not what else could i do? I'm thinking of creating new input and hiding old one and so after user finishes selecting everything, just submit all inputs at once, would that be the right way to do it?

Comment: how did you solve it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `multiple` attribute in `<input type=file>` is a new feature in HTML5 with limited browser support. Are you using html5 `doctype`? If so try with `multiple="multiple"` instead, or just `multiple`.
In any way, I suggest you use something like [plupload](http://www.plupload.com) for this.

**EDIT:**

To select multiple files you need to Shift+Select them.

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong. Try this [multiple file upload](http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/CUE9P/). Then click "browse" and shift+select multiple files and it should work.

Comment: i know how to select files :D you didn't understand my problem, anyways i solved it by my self.

Comment: Hey Linas.. Im having the same problem. Could you please share how you solved the problem?

Comment: @Linas can you share your solution for this?